# Counting the number of times a character appears in an array of strings in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, count, integer

Hi I'm writing a method that needs to check every element in an array for a given character and return the number of times the character appears altogether in the elements of the array.

For creating `squarenumbers` array I have this code:

```
 squarenumbers = []
 for k in 1..n
   squarenumbers << k**2
 end
 squarenumbers.map { |a| a.to_s }
 d.to_s
```

And to count the digit so far I have written:

```
for k in 0..n-1
   count =+1 if squarenumbers[k].include?"d" 
end
```

I have created an array of size `n` containing the square numbers from `1 to n` and I am now having trouble counting how many times the number `d` appears in each element.

I converted `d` to a string in the method and cannot understand why the count is not working. I apologise I'm a beginner but I thought what I've written would check each element in the array for the character d and add 1 to the counter every time a string contains it.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: add your `squarenumbers` array as well.

Comment: what d is doing? you are converting it to string? why? 2nd thing `squarenumbers.map { |a| a.to_s }` doesnt change `squarenumbers` squarenumbers is still an array of numbers. 3rd thing `squarenumbers[k]` will never have `'d'` in it so it will always return 0

Comment: @Manishh I converted d to a string because the way I was going to do this was convert the square numbers to strings and then use include? to count the number of times the number d appears in the numbers, but I've realised this won't work as it won't count repeats. Why does map not change the elements? Do I need to store this in a separate array? Why will it return zero if I use include and check each element of the array?

Comment: You need to replace the first sentence with a better description of the problem. My answer begins with one possible interpretation.

Comment: This question (even after edits to date) is extremely confusing, partially because you haven't shown how or where you are defining ```n``` or ```d```.  In addition, your description of the end goal doesn't seem to match what is actually happening with your code since defining ```n``` as an integer doesn't result in an array "...containing the square numbers from 1 to n".  It result in an array that contains squares OF the numbers 1-9.  More specifically, if ```n = 7```, should ```squarenumbers = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]```?  And if ```d = 9```, should ```count #=> 2```?

Answer (score 1):

My answer assumes that the problem is as follows: "Given an array of natural numbers (non-negative integers) and a digit `d` (an integer `0-9`), compute the total number of digits  equal to `d` for each element of the array and sum those totals over all elements of the array".

Note that this description makes no reference to perfect squares. That's because the way the array of natural numbers is constructed is irrelevant.

Let's first construct a method that computes the number of times a given digit `d` appears in a natural number `n`.

```
def digit_in_number_count(n, digit)
  n.digits.count(digit)
end
```

See [Integer#digits](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-digits) and [Array#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-count).

It's now just a matter of summing those counts over all elements in the array. Let `a` denote an array of natural numbers.

```
def digit_in_array_count(a, digit)
  a.sum { |n| digit_in_number_count(n, digit) }
end
```

See [Array#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum).

Here's an example.

```
a = [123425, 622252, 136407]
digit = 2

digit_in_number_count(123425, digit)
  #=> 2
digit_in_array_count(a, digit)
  #=> 6
```

`Integer#digits` and `Array#sum` both made their debut in Ruby v2.4. To support earlier versions of Ruby, you could modify the methods as follows.

```
def digit_in_number_count(n, digit)
  n.to_s.count(digit.to_s)
end

def digit_in_array_count(a, digit)
  a.reduce(0) { |t,n| t + digit_in_number_count(n, digit) }
end
```

See [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) ([a.k.a.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aka) `inject`) and [String#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-count).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm writing a method that needs to check every element in an array for
>   a given character and return the number of times the character appears
>   altogether in the elements of the array.

Assuming you have an array of strings then you can use `sum` and `count`.

```
['hello','one','two'].sum { |s| s.count('o') }
```

Comment: Or just `['hello','one','two'].join.count('o')`.

Comment: @SagarPandya Thanks for your answer, I have now edited my code, to this  squarenumbers = []
  for k in 1..n
 squarenumbers << k**2
 end
  strings = Array.new
  strings = squarenumbers.map {|a| a.to_s}
  d.to_s
  print strings.count(d)                                                                                               The count is returning nil though, why is this?

Answer (score 0):

For an array of numbers you could do:

```
squarenumbers.sum {|e| e.to_a.count(d)}
```

If `d` is numeric, you would want to change it to `d.to_s`